# Jenkins : Clone code from Git hub repository having 2FA authentication

Tags: github, jenkins

I was using Github normal credential in Jenkins to fetch code from one of the git hub repository . 
But recently the Github account has been changed to use 2FA (two face authentication).So I started using google authentication application for this. I was able to access repository using the 2FA but in jenkins I could find any solution to fetch code of scheduled jenkins jobs. 
Is there any workaround or Jenkins plugin through which I can handle 2FA authentication in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

2FA authentication can be bypassed by adding .ssh key to your github account. follow steps mentioned in url https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: Its not working for me also, i've tried with access token and SSH private key and Jenkins just times out. It seems like there is no possibility to checkout the repo by having 2FA enabled.

Comment: Hi could please share the location where you put your is_rsa.pub file? it should in yours user/.ssh folder.

Comment: Thats the place where i have it (id_rsa.pub)

Answer (score 0):

2FA authentication in jenkins can be handeled using the github pull request builder plugin 
Under the System configurations:

- go to the github pull request builder
- add credentials select kind as secret text
- add the personal access token here
- Test basic connection to GitHub by clicking on connect to API